# How to extend a list inside a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a pandas data frame, and each element of one of its columns is a list.
Then I have a list with the same amount of elements as rows in the pandas data frame; I want to extend the list inside pandas with this new list.

So, for example, if this is the data frame.

```py
my_column
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'my_column':[[1, 2], [3, 4]]})
```

and this is the external list

```py
external_list = [[5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

I want to extend each of the lists of the data frame, so the final result is:

```py
my_column
[1, 2, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 7, 8, 9]
```

For now, what I have is:

```py
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    df["my_column"].loc[index] = row["my_column"].extend(external_list[index])
```

Is there a more pythonic way?

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'my_column':[[1, 2], [3, 4]]})
lst = [[5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

One way:

```
df['my_column'] += pd.Series(lst)
```

Another way: You can `zip` the column values with list values and use list comprehension:

```
df['my_column'] = [l1 + l2 for l1, l2 in zip(df['my_column'].tolist(), lst)]
```

Output:

```
         my_column
0     [1, 2, 5, 6]
1  [3, 4, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether or not it's pythonic enough but you can do it this way:

```
data = {"my_column":[[1, 2], [3, 4]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

list2 = [[5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

df["my_column"] = [list1 + list2[i] for i, list1 in df["my_column"].iteritems()]
```